# Orthogonal system of functions

Tags: real-analysis, orthogonality

> Show that $$\{ 1/\sqrt{2\pi}, cos x/\sqrt{2\pi}, sin x/\sqrt{2\pi}, cos 2x/\sqrt{2\pi}, sin 2x/\sqrt{2\pi}, ... : n\in \mathbb{Z} \}$$ is an orthogonal system of functions on $[0, 2\pi]$.

**edit:** *I originally did the problem wrong, this is my new work.*

For the first term, $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ the result is trivial.

For all terms of the form $\dfrac{cos nx}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, however, I'm finding the following:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \varphi_{m}(x) \overline{\varphi_{n}(x)}dx = \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} cos^2nx = \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} (\dfrac{e^{inx} + e^{-inx}}{2})^2 = \dfrac{1}{8\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{i2nx} + 2 + e^{-i2nx} = \dfrac{1}{2}$$

Has my algebra gone wrong somewhere? I should find 1 for this integral, no?

Comment: You do not "**define** $\overline{\varphi}$": $\overline{z}$ is meant to be *precisely* the complex conjugate of $z$. In this case, since $x\in\Bbb R$, $\overline{\cos x}=\cos x$ and $\overline{\sin x}=\sin x$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli It seems I was very confused....I'll look at this again and come back if I have any questions! Thank you!

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I looked at the problem again but seem to have made a mistake somewhere...I fixed my work above.

Comment: The calculations are correct. The fact is that *orthogonal system* only requires $\langle x_\alpha, x_\beta\rangle=0\iff \alpha\ne\beta$. An orthogonal system is ortho*normal* when $\forall\alpha,\ \langle x_\alpha,x_\alpha\rangle=1$

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Ah, I had this written down incorrectly in my notes. Thank you!